# jwt token is throwing exception while decoding in yii2

Tags: yii2, jwt

jwt token is throwing exception while decoding in yii2. I have checked Token Value and it becomes
Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9jbWMtc2VydmVyLmFwaSIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2NtYy1zZXJ2ZXIuYXBpIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM1MDE1NzY3LCJuYmYiOjE1MzUwMTU3NjcsImp0aSI6NjIzLCJlbWFpbCI6InJvY2NvLmNhcHBhbGxhQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImRldmljZV9pZCI6ODUxfQ.5PDyFA_YtzKEvkFMhnmiwucVBf47IU3z9ejcmXUojIU

Once I removed the Bearer from the token then it is working fine.otherwise it is throwing an exception
"name": "Exception",
    "message": "Unknown JSON error: 5",
    "code": 0,
    "type": "DomainException",
    "file": "/Users/mds/Sites/cmc-server/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php",
    "line": 336,

What will be the problem please let me know.

Comment: you should retrieve token using some method

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method, pass your complete token to it, it will return you token part except `Bearer` and then decode that token

```
function getBearerToken() {
    $headers = $this->getAuthorizationHeader();
    // HEADER: Get the access token from the header
    if (!empty($headers)) {
        if (preg_match('/Bearer\s(\S+)/', $headers, $matches)) {
            return $matches[1];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note : You may need to modify it as per your needs

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I am concerned about, why at the beginning of token Bearer is added? is this a standard format?

Comment: It gets added in header to distinguish the authentication type.. Get more info here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108662/why-is-bearer-required-before-the-token-in-authorization-header-in-a-http-re